# Python Newbie Manipulating geo data on real "map"

Tags: python, dictionary, interactive

As the title states, I am new to python. Have been "messing" arround with it for a week or so. So now I have a grand idea like every newbie :) please no pitchforks ;).

I wounder if there is a way to import real Geodata/map data from the real world. In my case sea charts, these ussally display reefs, rocks and other usefull data. I also have a hobby where I set crab pots and I tought it would be a fun "project" to make a map where i could mark where I have but the pots, when the pot was set. Along with other data such as how many did i get last time etc. But due to my inexperience with python, it did not take long before I was dead i my tracks. I dont even know if python is the right tool for the job.
So question boils down to this. Is python able to do this ? Or do I need to jerry rig it with a million other things?

Again I am new, I have tried to google this. But the examples I found where somewhat over my head

Comment: I would suggest to ask more specific questions. I think people will down-vote your question because of this. And yes it is possible to do on Python

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Google Maps' Python client](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) for this? Their GitHub repository contains more information, and some example code, which might guide you in the right direction. From your post, it sounds like you're looking for a simple way to add points of interest to a map. Rather than creating your own map, it might be easier to get started by adding your POIs to Google Maps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx will def look into this :)

Comment: Consider using PostGIS with PostgreSQL (geospatial extension for Postgres) - also QGIS, ArchGIS, CartoDB. Those are geospatial databases and their extensions. Google Maps API is paid and will only give you data in google format - without having polygons locally.

Answer (score 0):

you could try my "fun" project... [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)!
It's goal is to provide a simple interface to create interactive maps in python...

So if you'd like to get some points on a map here's how you could do it:

```py
from eomaps import Maps
lon = [9.103193291366653, 9.107906546742054, 9.115986413099883, 9.122046312868255,
       9.11441532797475, 9.129003975565276, 9.129228416297437, 9.1294528570296] 
lat = [44.367615304539804, 44.35684214939603, 44.365595337950346, 44.35684214939603, 
       44.35975987891414, 44.350557808895495, 44.350557808895495, 44.350557808895495]
vals = [10, 30, 25, 47, 12, 34, 57, 23]

m = Maps(Maps.CRS.GOOGLE_MERCATOR)
m.set_data(data=vals, xcoord=lon, ycoord=lat, crs=4326)  # epsg:4236 == lon/lat
m.set_shape.geod_circles(radius=50) # draw the data as circles with a radius of 50m
m.plot_map() # actually plot the data

m.add_wms.OpenStreetMap.add_layer.default() # add openstreetmap as a background layer
m.cb.pick.attach.annotate() # get an annotation if you click on one of the datapoints
```

[image]